# Alignment of input in regression tables (Latex)

Tags: latex

I have created a regression table using the following commands:

```
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{adjustbox}{max
width={\textwidth},caption={Cumulative Average Abnormal Return},nofloat=table}
\begin{tabular}{l*{4}{c}}
\hline\hline
                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}\\
                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Test Model 1}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Test Model 2}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Test Model 3}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Test Model 4}\\
\hline
Window 1:\\
{[0]}               &      0.0254\sym{***}&      0.02565\sym{***}&      0.0431\sym{***}&      0.0495\sym{***}\\
                    &    (0.0024)         &    (0.0065)         &    (0.0098)         &    (0.0024)         \\
Window 2:\\
{[-1,-10]}           &    0.000249         &    0.000230         &    0.000276         &   0.0000194         \\
                    &   (0.00024)         &   (0.00092)         &   (0.00032)         &   (0.000322)         \\
{[-11,-20]}          &   0.0000232         &   -0.000242         &   -0.000242         &   -0.000232         \\
                    &    (0.0019)         &    (0.0019)         &    (0.0019)         &    (0.0023)         \\
Window 3:\\
{[1,10]}             &   -0.000124         &   -0.000436         &   -0.000321         &   -0.000232         \\
                    &    (0.0011)         &    (0.0010)         &    (0.0010)         &    (0.0010)         \\
{[11,20]}            &    0.000124         &    0.000124         &    0.000124         &    0.000124         \\
                    &    (0.0014)         &    (0.0014)         &    (0.0014)         &    (0.0015)         \\                                                                              

\hline
Observations        &         417         &         417         &         417         &         417         \\
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{5}{p{\textwidth}}{\footnotesize xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx}\\
\multicolumn{5}{p{\textwidth}}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.10\), \sym{**} \(p<0.05\), \sym{***} \(p<0.01\)}\\
\end{tabular}\end{adjustbox}

Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
```

This results in the following output:

[image: screenshot of output]

My question is, how can I align all the columns in the regression table and at the same the keep the table width equal to the text width. I also want to "link" the caption and the table text to the table so it does not end up on to different pages. Thank you!

Comment: Hi! Remember to mark the answer below as accepted, if it solves! :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me *how* you want to "align all the columns" in the table.

If you want to align the columns to the left, have them of equal width while keeping the overall width of the `tabular` equal to the `textwidth`, you can try changing

```latex
\begin{tabular}{l*{4}{c}}
```

to

```latex
\begin{tabular}{l*{4}{p{.2\textwidth}}}
```

or

```latex
\begin{tabular}{*{5}{p{.2\textwidth}}}
```

Please post a comment if this doesn't help!!